# Как нарастить память эмулятора?

Tags: android-sdk, android

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, что при установке приложения на эмулятор выскакивает ошибка `INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE`:

> `537 KB/s (40225545 bytes in 73.115s)`
> `pkg: /data/local/tmp/.-debug.apk`
> `Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE]`

В моем случае, нельзя использовать опцию манифеста (чтобы произвести установку на карточку)

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:installLocation="preferExternal"
    ... >
```

То есть приложение обязательно должно быть установлено во внутреннюю память устройства (эмулятора).

Как этого достичь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Запустить эмулятор из консоли с опцией partition-size (размер в Мб). Другие способы мне неизвестны.

```
emulator -avd avd_name -partition-size 512
```

Comment: Спасибо, это то, что нужно.